# Undefined symbols: .objc_class_name_UIScreen

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, linux

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I believe that I'm linking correctly but it always fails during linking the project I'm trying to build is just a simple UIScreen Hello World should be easy right if my toolchain is setup correctly(confirmed C,objc,c++ working. haven't been successful in testing the actual SDK though). I have included UIKit/UIScreen.h in HelloWorld.m(the only file that even mentions UIScreen) if needed I'll post code on pastebin. This is rather peculiar fails during linking yet I've linked against necessary libraries to my knowledge.

Output from attempted compilation:

```
arm-apple-darwin-gcc -c -I"/usr/local/include"  -I"/usr/local/include"  -F"/home/artillery/iPhone-1.1.4/System/Library/Frameworks"  -F"/iPhone-1.1.4/heavenly-1.1.4/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"  -DDEBUG -Wall -std=c99 -v3 -DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=1050 Classes/HelloWorldApp.m -o Classes/HelloWorldApp.o
arm-apple-darwin-gcc -arch arm -lobjc  -framework CoreFoundation  -framework Foundation  -framework UIKit  -framework CoreGraphics  -framework GraphicsServices  -framework CoreSurface  -L"/usr/local/lib" -F"/home/artillery/iPhone-1.1.4/heavenly-1.1.4/System/Library/Frameworks" -F"/home/artillery/iPhone-1.1.4/heavenly-1.1.4/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks" -bind_at_load -multiply_defined suppress -o HelloWorld Classes/HelloWorldApp.o Classes/main.o
/usr/local/bin/arm-apple-darwin-ld: Undefined symbols:
.objc_class_name_UIScreen
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloWorld] Error 1
```

ehh thought for sure this would get at least one response :(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to build an iOS application on an unsupported platform (e.g, Linux), using an ancient* unofficial development kit. This won't work -- the only supported development kit for iOS is Apple's XCode environment running on Mac OS X.

*: The references I found to "heavenly-1.1.4" online suggest that it was part of an unofficial dev kit released around 2008, before the official dev kit was released.

Comment: I'm well aware its "ancient" but an application designed for 1.1.4 IOS should compile fine, What would cause this error normally? its only failing at linking not at compiling I can link the UIKit Framework just fine as long as I don't mention UIScreen but as far as I know you need UIScreen to actually create a screen in which to add "widgets" to.

Comment: There was never an official development kit for iOS 1.1.4, so it's hard for me to tell for sure, but it's possible that UIScreen wasn't added until the release of iOS 2.0.

Comment: so I probably need to update my Headers and Libs to 2.0 as it stands the libs are from 1.1.4 and the headers are might be a combination of 1.1.4 and 2.0 Thanks I'll update those let you guys know the outcome :D

Comment: Oh yeah almost forgot I'm not looking to make appstore apps just general purpose utilities :D